# Redirect loop with nginx

Tags: nginx, odoo, nginx-reverse-proxy

Using nginx for SSL and reverse proxy functionality for Odoo. Had some issues earlier and had to rebuild the nginx config from scratch, and now I'm getting an endless redirect. Here's my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
upstream odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name odoo.site.com;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index       index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/odoo-mydomain-local.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/odoo-mydomain-local.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://odoo;
        # force timeouts if the backend dies
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set headers
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    # cache some static data in memory for 60mins
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: change the proxy_pass  from `http://odoo;` to `127.0.0.1:8069;`